# AngularJS routing , how to pass parameter with a url of view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to pass parameter `id` with url in **angularJS** ,
i try in **home.config** :

```
home.config(["$routeProvider",function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/profile",{
        templateUrl : "views/home/profile.html",
        controller  : "profile"
    })
    .when('/settings',{
        templateUrl : "views/home/settings.html",
        controller  : "Settings"
    })
    .when('/item',{
        templateUrl : "views/home/item.html",
        controller  : "item"
    });
```

}]);

in **home.html** :

```
<a href="#!item?id='+Item_id+'" >Item View</a>
```

and in **itemController**

```
controllers.controller("item",function ($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
 var url_string = window.location.href; // home.php#!/item?id=0ae8b2fc-3ccb-11e8-952b-708bcd9109ce
 var url = new URL(url_string);
 var item_id = url.searchParams.get("id");
 console.log(item_id);
})
```

but I get a `null` value, please help thanks in advance .

Comment: I think it's enough to have `ng-href="#!item?id={{Item_id}}"` and collect the id with `item_id  = $routeParams.id`

Comment: In home.config pass the id like this /item:itemId, then in the itemController assign $routeParams.itemId to some scope variable. Now you can use the scope variable in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ngRoute you should use $route in the controller to get the parameters of the route.

You can see working code here:

```
const app = angular.module("mainapp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/profile", {
      template: "<p>profile</p>",
      controller: function() {}
    })
    .when('/settings', {
      template: "<p>settings</p>",
      controller: function() {}
    })
    .when('/item', {
      template: "<p>item {{itemid}}</p>",
      controller: function($route, $scope) {
        $scope.itemid = $route.current.params.itemid;
      }
    });
}]);
```